# Angular Http get method for table

Tags: angular, api, angular-http

I'm new at angular and try to figure out how it works. I am trying to be pull data from API for my table.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
class AppComponent {
  people: any;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
}

interface people {
  userId:number;
  id:number;
  title:string;
  completed:boolean;
```

And this Html code-block

```
<tr *NgFor="let people of peoples">
              <td>{{people.userId}}</td>
              <td>{{people.id}}</td>
              <td>{{people.title}}</td>
              <td>{{people.completed}}</td>
```

where I'm doing wrong? Any advice very helpful.

Comment: `*NgFor="..."` -> `*ngFor="..."`

Comment: I would strongly suggest to read some more before starting to programming in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled the directive incorrectly, it's *ngFor, and also you're trying to reference a variable named peoples, which doesn't exist because in the component you named it people.

Check the console for errors in the future, and you should also read more because your code has a lot of bad practices. Try making use of services and put your http requests there and simply inject them into your components.